# Don't show tab characters as ^I or <09> in the output of :registers

Tags: register, tab-characters

If I type `:registers`, I see a lot of `<09>`:

```
"1   <09><09><09>d = self / i.to_f^J<09><09><09>r = d.to_s^J<09><09><09>p r =~ /0$/^J
"2   <09><09><09>puts ''^J
"3   <09><09><09>p "#{self}, #{i}"^J<09><09><09>p d^J
```

The `<09>` represents a Tab character; they're displayed in blue.

If I use `:set display&vim`, I get something marginally better:

```
"1   ^I^I^Id = self / i.to_f^J^I^I^Ir = d.to_s^J^I^I^Ip r =~ /0$/^J
"2   ^I^I^Iputs ''^J
"3   ^I^I^Ip "#{self}, #{i}"^J^I^I^Ip d^J
```

But it's still not useful enough to easily scan the output for the line I want..

I know this is a feature, and I understand why it's there, but I find this extremely unhelpful when looking for the register I want.

Is there any way to either not show it at all or show them as spaces?

Answer (score 4):

You chose to have them displayed that way by adding the `uhex` setting to the `'display'` option.  You can `:set display-=uhex` to restore the default behavior of displaying them as `^I`.

Getting `:reg` to display them differently would require a Vim patch, but some plugins provide displays of the registers in a scratch buffer, which may help.

- [Lord of the Regs](https://github.com/dahu/vim-lotr) provides a sidebar to display all the registers.
- [vimple](https://github.com/dahu/vimple) is a general Vim library, but it has a handy concept called an [overlay](https://github.com/dahu/vimple/blob/master/autoload/overlay.vim) ([example](https://github.com/dahu/vimple/blob/master/demo/jumplist.vim)).  You could use that to build a scratch buffer of the registers.  It's also easy to setup actions in that buffer.

Comment: Yeah, `^I` is marginally better than `<09>`, but it's still too noisy for my liking, as I can't easily scan the register list for the line I want...